# Example of good login/registration integration with social networks and openid?

Tags: facebook, authentication, openid, registration

We are at the early stages of creating a new website, at the point where we need to build the login/registration module.

I want to be looking forward to the future, so I want to allow my users to register and login using all sorts of accounts, such as OpenID, Google, Facebook, Yahoo, etc ...

My users are not all tech savvy, do you have an example of a site that managed to successfully implement a user-friendly "universal" login system?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/

:-)

The only confusing this is the box where you can type in any provider. (Dig that one away under an other heading).

Comment: I just noticed now that StackOverflow doesn't even let you signup without an OpenID. If you click on sign-up, you're taken to myOpenID ...

Comment: Yes, it's one of very few sites i don't need to guess a couple of times before hitting one of my 'i-don't-really-need-security'-passwords or sign up for a second time.

Comment: Also not, it isn't alien to non-techs because facebook uses pretty much the same approach when you add 3rd. party applications. It's the future, so I would recommend skipping the tradition approach.